# Why is my Headset playing through my Mic

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone, headset

I dont know why. But my headset sounds are playing through my mic.

Aka, if someone talks to me, they can hear them selves.
And game audio is playing through too.

Now, the first thing, is maybe the sound is too high .. and so its being Picked up by the mic.. But this is not the case.

Its like some audio setup bug..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted your operating system, but that sounds as if you have the "mix" setting enabled in your windows audio. Check your advanced settings in your audio.

Comment: Windows 7. Can you please explain where to find the mix setting.

Comment: I don't have 7, but when I do a search of "mix win 7 audio" a number of links pop up. Here is one of them that looks valuable: http://www.nowsmart.com/stereo-mix-windows-7.html

Comment: I have added the win 7 tag to your question.